# Accessing subfields in json file

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

Assuming I have a JSON file with the following structure. How I can access the names of the properties in the metadata field.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "basedoc_12kja": {
      "properties": {
        "created": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "dateOptionalTime"
        },
        "customerID": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "deleted": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "documentID": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "id": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "metadata": {
          "properties": {
            "Cert": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "Exp_date": {
              "format": "dateOptionalTime"
            },
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Mappings is an array of documents, each subfield of mappings has a different code. I want to obtain the metadata fields of each document to find out which metadata fields are common between them.

I haven't been able to instantiate this documents.

```
var response = esReader.GetIndicesMapping();

foreach (var mapping in response.Response.Values)
{
   // Parse JSON into dynamic object, convenient!
   dynamic results = JObject.Parse(mapping);

   List<DocumentType> deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DocumentType>>(mapping);

}
```

**Exception**

> {"Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DocumentType]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.\r\nPath 'mappings', line 2, position 14."}

The desire result is to obtain the name of `Cert` and `Exp_date` fields

**EDIT**

```
public class DocumentType
    {

        public string Id { set { DocumentID = value; } get { return DocumentID; } }

        public string DocumentID { set; get; }       

        public DateTime Created { set; get; }
         .
         .
         .
        public Dictionary<string, object> Metadata { set; get; }


    }
```

Comment: You're trying to deserialize into a List of DocumentType when all you have is a single complex object in your JSON.

Comment: It doesn't help that we can't see the `DocumentType` class... a short but *complete* example demonstrating the problem would really help here.

Comment: @JonSkeet I added the DocumentType class, hope it help. Thanks

Comment: Well that's still not a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, is it? I would like something I can copy, paste, compile and run - in this case with an additional copy/paste/save cycle for the JSON.

Comment: You should also consider to use `{ get; set; }` instead of `{ set; get; }` as this is the _"officially"_ way microsoft (e.g. msdn) does. Anyway that's just a matter of appearance, I think.

Comment: Try pasting your JSON to http://json2csharp.com/ and then add that classes to your project and then deserialize json into the base class

Comment: @imannemati That would be an excellent solution, but unfortunately each entry on the mapping has a different name for each document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have here is a hierarchical dictionary of named properties, where each property can have a type, a format, and possibly a nested dictionary of named child properties -- `metadata` in your case.  You can represent this with the following data model:

```
[DataContract]
public class PropertyData
{
    [DataMember(Name="type", EmitDefaultValue=false)]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "format", EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string Format { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "properties", EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public Dictionary<string, PropertyData> Properties { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Mappings
{
    [DataMember(Name = "mappings", EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public Dictionary<string, PropertyData> DocumentMappings { get; set; }
}
```

(This data model doesn't capture the fact that a given property (probably) can only be a simple type or a complex type with nested properties - but not both.  It would seem to suffice for your needs however.)

Then, given the JSON above, you would read it in and convert it to a dictionary of document name to metadata property name as follows:

```
        var mappings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Mappings>(json);
        Debug.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mappings, Formatting.Indented));  // Verify that all was read in.
        var metadataNames = mappings.DocumentMappings.ToDictionary(doc => doc.Key, doc => doc.Value.Properties["metadata"].Properties.Select(p => p.Key).ToList());
        Debug.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(metadataNames, Formatting.Indented)); // Inspect the resulting mapping table.
```

And the result is the dictionary of metadata names you want:

> ```
> {
>   "basedoc_12kja": [
>     "Cert",
>     "Exp_date"
>   ]
> }
> ```

If you are concerned that the nested `metadata` might be missing sometimes and so generate `NullReferenceExceptions` in the query above, you can add null checks as follows:

```
// Extension methods to query or walk through nested properties, avoiding null reference exceptions when properties are missing
public static class PropertyDataExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, PropertyData>> GetProperties(this PropertyData data)
    {
        if (data == null || data.Properties == null)
            return Enumerable.Empty<KeyValuePair<string, PropertyData>>();
        return data.Properties;
    }

    public static PropertyData GetProperty(this PropertyData data, string name)
    {
        if (data == null || data.Properties == null)
            return null;
        PropertyData child;
        if (!data.Properties.TryGetValue(name, out child))
            return null;
        return child;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
        var metadataNamesSafe = mappings.DocumentMappings.ToDictionary(doc => doc.Key, doc => doc.Value.GetProperty("metadata").GetProperties().Select(p => p.Key).ToList());
```

Comment: I like this answer better.  The key realization here is that every object has some combination of "type" "format" and "properties" which makes things look much simpler.

Comment: Thank you both dbc and Moby Disk (because with your comment you are making me my decision easier). This is a great answer too!

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that your data structure does not match the JSON:

1. There are no arrays in the JSON.  So there is no way you will be able to deserialize that into a C# List.
2. The "DocumentType" class doesn't match the JSON at all.  The class has properties Created, CustomerID, and Deleted which are things like DateTime and string.  But the JSON doesn't have those as DateTime or string.  They are objects with subproperties named "type" and "format."  The property "Metadata" isn't a dictionary: it is an object with a single property named "properties" which should probably be a dictionary.
3. The case doesn't match.
4. Don't do that weird thing with Id and DocumentId.  The class should match the JSON exactly and literally.  No business logic hidden in properties.
5. The root object has a property called "mappings" so you will need to drill-down before you get to the documents.
6. Once you successfully get the document, you will need to drill down to the property named "properties" to get to the fields you are interested in.

I suspect there could be multiple documents, and that the "mappings" property contains a list of those documents, where the property names are dynamic and correspond to the name of the document.  It is entirely plausible to handle that but not using a deserialization + List approach.

I see 3 approaches here:

1. Fix the JSON.  Not sure if this is possible in your case.  If so, start by making mappings hold an array instead of having each document be a property named by the document name.
2. Fix the deserialization code to match the JSON document.  json2csharp did an excellent job so start with that.  It just doesn't know that "mappings" is really a Dictionary, not just a thing with a property named "basedoc12_kja."
3. Don't deserialize it at all.  Just query for the metadata.  take a look at http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm which shows several ways to query JSON using JObject properties and LINQ.

**Option 1**

Example of a slightly cleaned-up JSON if you go that route:

```
{
  "mappings": [
    {
        "name"" : "basedoc_12kja",
        "properties": {
          ""created": "20150522",
          etc.
   },
```

Notice "mappings" is an array and the name became a property of the document.  Now you can make a List<> or use JArray.  Even better is to get rid of the unused stuff at the top, like this:

```
[
   {
      "name" : "basedoc_12kja",
      "properties": {
         "created"": "20150522",
         etc.
   },
]
```

Now it is just an array with no "mappings" at all.

** Option 2 **
Here is code that will do this via deserialization.  There are two parts.  Step one is to use what json2charp produced.  I'll include that here for reference:

```
public class Created
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string format { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerID
{
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Deleted
{
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class DocumentID
{
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Id
{
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Cert
{
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class ExpDate
{
    public string format { get; set; }
}

public class Properties2
{
    public Cert Cert { get; set; }
    public ExpDate Exp_date { get; set; }
}

public class Metadata
{
    public Properties2 properties { get; set; }
}

public class Properties
{
    public Created created { get; set; }
    public CustomerID customerID { get; set; }
    public Deleted deleted { get; set; }
    public DocumentID documentID { get; set; }
    public Id id { get; set; }
    public Metadata metadata { get; set; }
}

public class Basedoc12kja
{
    public Properties properties { get; set; }
}

public class Mappings
{
    public Basedoc12kja basedoc_12kja { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Mappings mappings { get; set; }
}
```

Then, rename Basedoc12kja to DocumentType, and change RootObject to hold a dictionary.  You get this:

```
public class DocumentType
{
    public Properties properties { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Dictionary<string, DocumentType> mappings { get; set; }
}
```

And if you want to get to properties other than just Cert and Exp_date then change Metadata to this:

```
public class Metadata
{
    public Dictionary<string,object> properties { get; set; }
}
```

Now that can deserialize your document:

```
JObject results = JObject.Parse(mapping);
RootObject ro = results.ToObject<RootObject>()
```

You can enumerate through the mappings and get to the properties.  They are still messy because of the JSON structure, but you can at least get there.

I hope this helps!

Comment: It is amazing how detailed is your answer, thank you very much for your time!. It should works, I will test it.